# Why does jQuery.keydown not fire the first letter I type?

Tags: jquery

Why does `jQuery.keydown` not fire the first letter I type?

http://jsfiddle.net/AstRc/

```
<input id="foo" type="text">
<div></div>

$("#foo").on('keydown', function(e){
    $("div").text(this.value);
});
```

I only see it fire on the 2nd keydown press, not the first.

Comment: use keyup instead of keydown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `keydown` event is being fired, the value in the textbox hasn’t changed yet. It seems like you’re looking for the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input) anyways (use `'input keyup'` for backwards compatibility). [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/AstRc/1/)

Comment: anyway to get the value after it is there?

Comment: @chovy: Yep; `input`, preferably, with `keyup` as a fallback.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are looking for solution but you can use instead:

```
$("#foo").on('keyup', function(e){
    $("div").text(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do the update in the `keydown` event, you can start with something that look like this but there will be many situations where this will not work as expected. You will have to manage many exceptions using the e.keyCode value

```
$("#foo").on('keydown', function(e){
    var content = $("div").text();
    $("div").text(content+String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
    if (e.keyCode==8) { $("div").text(content.slice(0,-1)); }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AstRc/4/)**